# Sorting the list by two parameters simultaneously C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I would like to sort lists with structures by certain fields/properties of structures. For example there is a structure:

```
public struct Some
{
    public int index;
    public DateTime date;
}
```

Do I have an opportunity to sort such a structure by two parameters simultaneously using the existing methods? Say, at the top of the list of such structures place those that will have the latest `date` and the largest `index`. Is it possible to sort simultaneously taking into account these two parameters?

Comment: afaik, you should choose one main criterion first using `OrderBy` then use `ThenBy` for the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

with the [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0) method

`OrderBy` and `ThenBy` are the mothods you need.

Example:

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.index).ThenBy(x => x.date)
```

If you add [Descending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0) you can also sort it the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom sort comparison function.

**Example 1:**

```cs
    public struct MyItem
    {
        public int index;
        public DateTime date;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new MyItem[]{
                new MyItem{index=9, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=4, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=3, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=5, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=5, date=DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)},
                new MyItem{index=6, date=DateTime.Now},
            };
            // sort by index, if equal then sort by date
            Array.Sort(items, (x, y) =>
            {
                if (x.index == y.index)
                    return x.date.CompareTo(y.date);
                return x.index.CompareTo(y.index);
            });

            foreach (var item in items)
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.index} {item.date}");
        }
    }
```

**Example 2:**

```cs
var items = new List<MyItem>{
    new MyItem{index=9, date=DateTime.Now},
    new MyItem{index=4, date=DateTime.Now},
    new MyItem{index=3, date=DateTime.Now},
    new MyItem{index=5, date=DateTime.Now},
    new MyItem{index=5, date=DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)},
    new MyItem{index=6, date=DateTime.Now},
};
// sort by index, if equal then sort by date
items.Sort((x, y) => x.index.CompareTo(y.index) == 0 ? x.date.CompareTo(y.date) : x.index.CompareTo(y.index));
```

**Example3:** Linq

```cs
            var items = new List<MyItem>{
                new MyItem{index=9, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=4, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=3, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=5, date=DateTime.Now},
                new MyItem{index=5, date=DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)},
                new MyItem{index=6, date=DateTime.Now},
            };
            // sort by index, if equal then sort by date
            var newItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.index).ThenBy(x => x.date);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `Sort` *in place* and you don't want to implement `IComparable<Some>` or `IComparer<Some>`:

```
List<Some> myList = ...

...

myList.Sort((left, right) => {
  // latest dates on the top (note - for descending sorting)
  int result = -left.date.CompareTo(right.date);

  // on tie when left and right have the same date we compare indexes
  return result == 0 
    ? -left.index.CompareTo(right.index)
    :  result; 
});
```

In case you have *several* fragments where you want to sort list in such a way, you can implement a *comparer*:

```
public sealed class SomeComparer : IComparer<Some> { 
  public int Compare(Some left, Some right) {
    // latest dates on the top (note - for descending sorting)
    int result = -left.date.CompareTo(right.date);

    // on tie when left and right have the same date we compare indexes
    return result == 0 
      ? -left.index.CompareTo(right.index)
      :  result;
  }
}
```

Then whenever you want to sort the list:

```
myList.Sort(new SomeComparer());
```

Finally, if it's the only order you want to sort `Some` items, you can make `Sort` comparable:

```
public struct Some : IComparable<Some>
{
    public int index;
    public DateTime date;

    //TODO: implement Equals and GetHashCode 

    public bool CompareTo(Some other) {
      int result = -date.CompareTo(other.date);

      return result == 0 
        ? -index.CompareTo(other.index)
        : result;
    }
}
```

and you can put

```
myList.Sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to easily sort items in a list by the values contained in a that list.

```
using System.Linq;

...

myStructs.OrderBy(s => s.index).ThenBy(s => s.date)
```

Will put everything in order by index. Items with equal index would be sorted by date.